# Having Issue while upgrade Apache Cassandra from 3.x to 4.x version

Tags: node.js, cassandra-3.0, cassandra-4.0

We are planning to perform Apache Cassandra upgrade activity from 3.x version to 4.x(4.0)
Application is based on Node js project. Current node js driver we are using to connect Cassandra is ----> "Cassandra-driver": "^3.1.1", inside package.json
I would like to know same node js driver version we can use for Apache Cassandra 4.0 or not.
Any document to verify node js driver for Cassandra 4.0.
So let me know if we can use same node js driver for Cassandra 4.0 or not. If not what could be the compatible driver version for Cassandra 4.0.Below is my application configuration:
Application - Node js
Node js driver - 3.1.1 (inside package .json)
Cassandra version - 3.11.2 (Currently we are using but need to upgrade with 4.0)